# Vim: What is the difference between these two methods of setting a variable?

Tags: vim, vimrc

In my **.vimrc**, I have the following variable defined:

```
let $VIMFILES = "~/.vim"
```

Further in my **.vimrc**, I attempt to set the `backupdir` option like so:

```
set backupdir=$VIMFILES/backup
" `set backupdir?` will return: backupdir=~/.vim/backup
```

However, it does not work. Attempting to `:w` a file will fail and return the following:

```
"foo" E510: Can't make backup file (add ! to override)
```

Strangely enough, setting `backupdir` using the following method works just fine...

```
exec "set backupdir=" . $VIMFILES . "/backup"
" Like the first method, `set backupdir?` will
" also return: backupdir=~/.vim/backup
```

Can anyone shed light as to why the first method fails and the second method works, despite `backupdir` having the desired value in both cases? Am I using any improper techniques, and if so, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this, and indeed, it looks quite puzzling. One tricky thing is that `:set backupdir?` does not necessarily print the actual option value; it performs some transformations, so what you see is not always what is used.

I think the problem lies in the use of the `~/` in the `$VIMFILES` variable. When you directly `:set` the option (as emulated by the last `:execute` attempt), Vim seems to automatically expand that. But when you assign that to an environment variable, it is kept verbatim, and due to the lack of expansion, the `:write` fails. Note that the output is identical because Vim apparently automatically translates `/home/username` back to `~` in the output.

I would solve this by explicitly expanding the variable value:

```
let $VIMFILES = expand("~/.vim")
```

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight! I was not aware of how and when Vim internally expanded the variables. You're quite right about `set` transforming the value too. For example, `:echo expand("~/.vim/backup")` returns: `/home/zeroknight/.vim/backup`, and `:set backupdir?` returns: `~/.vim/backup`. Thank you again for the solution and the insight!